# Confused about how to Populate DropDown thru ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am a beginner to ASP.NET MVC technology. In my controller page I am using this code below

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult UrunEkle() {

    List<SelectListItem> degerler = (from i in db.tblKategoriler.ToList()
                                     select new SelectListItem
                                     {
                                         Text = i.KategoriAd,
                                         Value = i.KategoriId.ToString()
                                     }).ToList();

    ViewBag.dgr = degerler;
 
    return View(degerler);
}
```

this is view page

```
model  MVCSTOK.Models.Entity.tblKategoriler 

<div>
    <label>Ürün Kategori</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.KategoriAd,(List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.dgr, new { @class = "form-control" }); 
</div>
```

I am geting this  error

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MVCSTOK.Models.Entity.tblKategoriler.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your returning data's type isn't corresponding to `MVCSTOK.Models.Entity.tblKategoriler`, that you return it from `UrunEkle()` Action method. You return `List<SelectListItem>`, but your View's type of model is  `MVCSTOK.Models.Entity.tblKategoriler`.

I think you can do (return view without model):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult UrunEkle() {

    List<SelectListItem> degerler = (from i in db.tblKategoriler.ToList()
                                     select new SelectListItem
                                     {
                                         Text = i.KategoriAd,
                                         Value = i.KategoriId.ToString()
                                     }).ToList();

    ViewBag.dgr = degerler;
 
    return View();
}
```

And you can do this in .cshtml view (without model):

```
<div>
    <label>Ürün Kategori</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.KategoriAd,(List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.dgr, new { @class = "form-control" }); 
</div>
```